# Multiple rows with same value in one column

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Hello I have a problem with following case.
I have a table "Application log" as

```
App_name        date         status
Application 1   10-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   11-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   12-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 1   13-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   14-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   15-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 1   16-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   17-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   18-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 1   19-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   20-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   21-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 1   22-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   23-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   25-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 3   20-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 3   21-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 3   22-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 3   23-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 3   24-MAR-17   FAILED
```

I have to find 'n' consequential failed status for one application_name and return it as result. For example if n=5 my query must return app_name = Application 3.

Comment: your question is not clear enough

Comment: Is application 3 also a fail for `n` in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}?

Comment: yes also fail for n  in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query works in SQL Server. I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work in Oracle as well:

```
SELECT [App_name]
FROM (
   SELECT [App_name], [date], [status],
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY App_name ORDER BY [date]) 
          -
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY App_name, 
                                          CASE 
                                             WHEN status = 'FAILED' THEN 1
                                             ELSE 2 
                                          END 
                             ORDER BY [date]) AS grp
   FROM ApplicationLog) AS t
WHERE status = 'FAILED'   
GROUP BY [App_name], grp
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/CYKXI52602)

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach utilizing only a single OLAP-function:

```
SELECT App_name, Max(date) AS LastFail
FROM
 (
   SELECT App_name, date, status,
       -- check if the last 5 rows only contain FAILED
          Min(CASE WHEN status = 'FAILED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) 
          Over (PARTITION BY App_name
                ORDER BY date
       -- caution, as this includes the current row it must be n-1
                ROWS 4 Preceding) AS x
   FROM ApplicationLog
 ) AS t
WHERE x = 1
GROUP BY App_name
```